# Atomのパッケージ「autocomplete-paths」のwindowsでの補完について

Tags: atom-editor

Atom：version1.0.2 
autocomplete-paths：v1.0.2

win7でAtomを利用し、パッケージ「autocomplete-paths」を使用しているのですが、補完されるパスが全てバックスラッシュ「\」になってしまい、毎回消してスラッシュ「/」を打ち直す手間が発生しています。

最初から「/」にする方法はないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 要望は出されてますが解決していないようですね。https://github.com/atom-community/autocomplete-paths/issues/49

Comment: ありがとうございます。英語なので内容がよくわからないのですが、今のところ方法はなさそうということでしょうか・・・。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

正式に対応されるまでの暫定対応としてパッケージの中に手を加えても良いということであれば、下記の手順で変えられると思います。

1. 「Settings」を開く
2. メニュー最下部の「Open Config Folder」を押下（Atomが別で上がります）
3. tree viewで下記まで移動
   .atom -> packages -> autocomplete-paths -> libs
4. paths-provider.coffeeを開く
5. L.92辺りを下記のように編集
   `result += path.sep` -> `result += '/'`
6. 保存して閉じる
7. Atom再起動（いらないかもしれません）

Comment: ありがとうございます。'/'に変更したところ、補完後に次の候補はでませんが、ほぼ解決しました。一旦この状態で使っていきます。助かりました。
(再起動は必要でした)